# макрос для замены текста с использованием буфера

Tags: notepad++

подскажите, это вообще возможно записать макрос, где в целом одна замена, но чтобы замена была не на что-то конкретное, а на текст только что скопированный в буфер?

пример:
Wilco - Far Far Away (Dark Side of the Room) #Writer
Wilco - Out of Sight, out of Mind (Alternate) #Writer
Wilco - Hesitation Rocks #Writer
Wilco - Outtasite (Outta Mind) [Early Version] [Take 6] #Writer
Wilco - Lost Love (Take 1 Vocal 2) #Writer
Wilco - Losing Interest #Writer

нужно заменить "Writer" на "Jeff Tweedy"

хочется забить это всё в макрос, чтобы каждый раз не тратить время, а просто решать вопрос парой клавиш

когда пишешь макрос для замены, программа фиксирует определённый текст "на что меняем" а мне нужно именно чтобы замена происходила на то, что в данный момент в буфере обмена...

реально ли это?

или надо этот текст написать в шапке документа и уже как-то регулярками решать вопрос?